# How to make an application run automatically?

Tags: login, rpm, profile

I am trying to run my application when a user logs in. So I've added a script in `~/.bash_profile` as follows:

```
# for Buluttdepo
/usr/bin/myapp > /dev/null 2>&1 &
export MYAPP_HOME=/opt/myapp
```

It is run successfully, but should I add the script in `.bash_profile`?

Otherwise I can add in `/etc/profile` or add a script file as `/etc/profile.d/myapp_run.sh` . If I do it this way, myapp is run by root. But I don't want to run it by root. I should run by any user.

Therefore, I'm building an RPM package. I want to add the script when the RPM package installer is run. Because the RPM package is installed by root, it doesn't know which `.bash_profile` to add to, so it can add only to `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d/`.

- Which file should I add it to?

  - If the file is `~/bash_profile`, how to add the script in `bash_profile` for *any user* by `root` via `rpm`?
  - If the file is `/etc/profile` , how can any user run `myapp`?
  - Can you suggest a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Why is it mandatory that the application run on login? Must it also run on console login?

Comment: `/etc/profile` isn't for root only, all users (using a shell which supports `/etc/profile`) will source it when the shell is a login shell.

Comment: If I add `/usr/bin/myapp > /dev/null 2>&1 &` in profile, it is run by root. I want to run for any user.

Comment: It sounds that what you want is for `myapp` to run for each user on each user's login. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, if a user has login, myapp should is run.

Comment: "when a user logs in" in what? If it's X server, you could just drop `myapp` in the $HOME/.xinitrc file.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like `cron` would solve what you're trying to do.

The general format of a crontab looks something like this, with each column representing the minute, hour, day of the month, month and day of the week, respectively.

```
30 * * * * /home/user/updates.sh
```

Cron also supports a few predefined entries such as `@weekly`, `@daily` and amongst these is `@reboot`.

You can either edit the `crontab` while logged into the user you wish to run the script from using `crontab -e` or as root `crontab -u username -e` to edit another user's `crontab`.

Once you have your editor open, add:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/myapp > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The next time you reboot the machine, `/usr/bin/myapp` will be run by the user whose crontab you put it into.

Answer (score 1):

A package installation script touching files in home directories is a definite no-no. You are highly likely to disrupt the user's configuration, and it may or may not work (what if the user has zsh or tcsh as his login shell?), and it only applies for users whose home directory is around at the time the package is installed.

It is extremely strange to run an application whenever a user logs in. It is up to each user to choose whether he wants to run your application.

If you need to execute code when a user logs in, modifying `/etc/profile` is your best bet. If your distribution has a directory `/etc/profile.d`, drop a file there instead of modifying `/etc/profile`. If you must modify `/etc/profile`, be very careful not to disrupt the system administrator's customizations. Typically all you'd do in `profile` is to set an environment variable.

You claim that “If I do it this way, myapp is run by root”. That's just false: `/etc/profile` is executed by the user who's logging in.

To reiterate, what you should probably do is tell users “if you want to run my application, run the `myapp` command or select ‘My App’ from the menu or click [image]”, nothing more. Be sure to provide a menu entry for GUI users. To avoid fiddling with environment variables, provide a calling script that sets any necessary environment variable.